Is there an existing problem related to inferring a hidden node in a graph from its neighbors
My original question was a bit too ambiguous, so I updated it as follows:
Consider a graph $G=(V,E)$. A vertex in $G$ is chosen uniformly at random; then a neighbor $x$ of $v$ is chosen uniformly at random among the neighbors of $v$. You are told $x$ and asked to guess $v$.
What is the worst case number of guesses for a given graph?
The most naive approach to finding the worst cause would be taking the maximum degree of the nodes in the graph $\Delta(G)$. A strategy given the node $x$ would be to guess the neighbors with the least degree (e.g., as these are more likely to have $x$ selected).
Question: However, I am not asking for a solution to this problem. I am wondering if there is an existing problem similar to this problem.
Example:
I formulated this as a graph problem, but in general, it is a problem of making prediction based on relationships (except the randomness may not be uniform in general). For example, consider a set of classes where each class (e.g., diseases) is associated with a set of attributes (e.g., symptoms).
Given the symptoms, what is the disease? Assuming our database of diseases and symptoms is 100% accurate, we could estimate the worst case accuracy of our prediction based on the given symptoms. Further, we could estimate the worst case accuracy of our prediction without knowledge of the symptoms.

Your question seems very vague, but maybe related is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship_paradox

@SamHopkins Yea, I agree. I apologize my question is vague. There some similarity to the Friendship Paradox, but my question would be more analogous to "how accurately can a person be identified given only a subset of their friends"

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Suppose the model is this: a vertex $v$ in $G$ is chosen uniformly at random; then a neighbor $x$ of $v$ is chosen uniformly at random among neighbors of $v$. You are told $x$ and asked to guess $v$. There is still some strategy here. Not all neighbors of $x$ are equal in this scenario. It is best to guess the neighbor of $x$ with the least degree (i.e., who has the least neighbors). Do you see why?

@SamHopkins Ah, yes I see. I updated my question based on your more concise descriptions along with an example application to help make more sense of the problem.

Well at this level of generality, your problem (guess the true state of affairs based on partial empirical data) essentially encompasses all of statistics, so I don't know if it's a great fit for this site.

@Ralff:  "Causal Inference" might be of interest here.

@AugustoSantos Thanks! This seems to be related after a quick search. I will look into it more!

@SamHopkins I don't quite understand why this wouldn't be a good fit here. Isn't mathoverflow for mathematics research? While the analogy I provide is more data science, my question is more about combinatorics or graph theory -- I just thought of this analogy to make the problem grounded in reality.
